# Salt Stack Configuration for Rackspace/Cloud Providers

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am trying to configure Salt Stack 2014.1.0 for cloud providers...specifically for Rackspace. I found a really good article http://salt-cloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/rackspace.html which is more up to date than the Salt Stack site for cloud providers(Rackspace one on SaltStack site pre-openstack). But even this external guide is old from 2013.

Following http://salt-cloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/rackspace.html with Salt 2014.1.0, I will need to manually create /etc/salt/cloud.providers.d/ because it is not there. But how to I make salt point to it/use it? I see no directive in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg to point to it.

Comment: It is a bit in flux. I /think/ the idea is to use either salt states or salt runners to execute salt-cloud on a target minion to manage the cloud. So the new paradigm exposes salt-cloud API to the runner API.  Or something.  I'm a bit confused about it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Salt-cloud by default is compiled to look in a five directories for various configuration files:

- cloud.conf.d
- cloud.deploy.d
- cloud.maps.d
- cloud.profiles.d
- cloud.providers.d

Each *.conf file placed in those directories is processed alongside the corresponding single file location (`/etc/salt/cloud`, `/etc/salt/cloud.profiles`, `/etc/salt/cloud.providers`, etc)

If your salt master is Ubuntu with the SaltStack PPA, just `apt-get install salt-cloud` and it'll create all those directories for you.

The minimum you'll need to get things going is one provider and one profile.  Put this in `/etc/salt/cloud.providers.d/rackspace.conf`:

```
openstack-rackspace:
  minion:
    master: <YOUR-SALT-MASTER>

  provider: openstack
  compute_name: cloudServersOpenStack
  identity_url: 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens'
  #identity_url: 'https://lon.identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens'
  protocol: ipv4

  # Rackspace regions:
  # DFW (Dallas), ORD (Chicago), IAD (Virginia), SYD (Sydney), HKG (Hong Kong)
  # LON (London) requires a separate Rackspace UK account and different URL above.
  compute_region: ORD

  # Rackspace username, apikey and account number
  user: <YOUR-RACKSPACE-USERNAME>
  apikey: <YOUR-RACKSPACE-API-KEY
  tenant: <YOUR-RACKSPACE-ACCOUNT-NUMBER>
```

And then put the following into `/etc/salt/cloud.profiles.d/myprofile.conf`

```
#Std: [1GB,2GB,4GB,8GB,15GB,30GB] Standard Instance
#P1: performance1-[1,2,4,8]
#P2: performance2-[15,30,60,90,120]

#2GB, 1vCPU, 40GB HD, 120Mbit
my-standard_2gb:
  provider: openstack-rackspace
  size: 2GB Standard Instance
  image: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) (PVHVM)

#2GB, 2vCPU, 40GB SSD, 400Mbit
web_2gb:
  provider: openstack-rackspace
  size: performance1-2
  image: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) (PVHVM)
  grains:
    role: web
    blah: production
```

List all available images with:
`salt-cloud --list-images openstack-rackspace`

List all available sizes with:
`salt-cloud --list-sizes openstack-rackspace`

Create a new instance with:
`salt-cloud -p web_2gb unique.machine.name` but you're on your own for DNS.